# Count characters in lo..ol and print a phrase

Tags: code-golf, string

Assuming 'lol' with a variavle number of 'o's. Print a the following phrase:

```
What does 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... 'o' stand for?
```

Examples:

```
lol    -> What does 1st 'o' stand for?
loooool -> What does 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th 'o' stand for?
```

So far I managed to write a 128 characters solution in Perl:

```
$l=(<>=~tr/o//);print"What does ";print$_,$_==1?'st':$_==2?'nd':$_==3?'rd':'th',$_<$l?', ':''for(1..$l);print " 'o' stand for?";
```

and a 123 characters solution in Haskell:

```
p 1="1st";p 2="2nd";p 3="3rd";p n=show n++"th";main=putStr$"What does "++(foldr(++)"'o' stand for?"[p i++", "|i<-[1..23]]);
```

How short can you write it?

Comment: Does it work for `'ll'`? I assume not

Comment: You can assume number of 'o' to be >0.

Comment: Yes. But that increases difficulty, somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 82 characters

```
"What does "\,2-,{)..10/10%1=!\10%`"123"\?)*"thstndrd"2/=+}%", "*" 'o' stand for?"
```

Works even for >100 'o's, [test it online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oydsb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29sJwoKIldoYXQgZG9lcyAiXCwyLSx7KS4uMTAvMTAlMT0hXDEwJWAiMTIzIlw%2FKSoidGhzdG5kcmQiMi89K30lIiwgIioiICdvJyBzdGFuZCBmb3I%2FIgoK&run=true).

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 112

```
print'What does '+', '.join(`n+1`+['th','snrtdd'[n::3]][n<3]for n in range(len(raw_input())-2)),"'o' stand for?"
```

Comment: very nice slicing trick...

Comment: Unfortunately does not work for number of 'o's greater than 20.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 104 (+1) bytes

```
s/l?ol?/($`?', ':"What does the ").++$n.((0,st,nd,rd)[$n%(10<<($n%100<20))]||th)/ge;s/$/ 'o' stand for?/
```

Correctly handles `11th, 12th, 13th`, `21st, 22nd, 23rd`, `111th, 112th, 113th` etc. Takes input from stdin, and requires a `-p` command line switch:

```
$ echo loooool| perl -p loool.pl
What does the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th 'o' stand for?

$ echo looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool| perl -p loool.pl
What does the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th,
15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th,
30th, 31st, 32nd, 33rd, 34th, 35th, 36th, 37th, 38th, 39th, 40th, 41st, 42nd 'o' stand for?
```

If it is not required that `21st, 22nd, 23rd` be reported correctly (as in the example code), this can be reduced to **87 bytes**:

```
s/l?ol?/($`?', ':"What does the ").++$n.((0,st,nd,rd)[$n]||th)/ge;s/$/ 'o' stand for?/
```

---

### PHP 107 bytes

```
What does the <?for(;$argv[1][++$n]>l;$f=', ')echo$f,$n,date(S,~-$n%(10<<($n%100<20))*9e4)?> 'o' stand for?
```

Input is taken by command line argument:

```
$ php loool.php loooool
What does the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th 'o' stand for?

$ php loool.php looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool
What does the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th,
15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th,
30th, 31st, 32nd, 33rd, 34th, 35th, 36th, 37th, 38th, 39th, 40th, 41st, 42nd 'o' stand for?
```

Once again, if correctly handling `n>20` is not required, this can be reduced to **87 bytes**:

```
What does the <?for(;$argv[1][++$n]>l;$f=', ')echo$f,date(jS,~-$n*9e4)?> 'o' stand for?
```

Answer (score 1):

### R - 158 characters

```
f=function(s){n=1:(nchar(s)-2);v=c("st","nd","rd",rep("th",7));cat("What does the",paste0(n,c(v,rep("th",10),rep(v,8))[n],collapse=", "),"\"o\" stand for?")}
```

Works until 100 "o"s.

Usage:

```
f("looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool")
What does the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th, 31st, 32nd, 33rd, 34th "o" stands for?
```